# Sed doesn't remove word with comma + space

Tags: bash, sed

I have this part of code in bash which should remove all occurences of the first word in `$content` from it:

```
fst_word=$(echo $content | { read fst _; echo $fst; })
content=$(echo $content | sed "s/\b$fst_word\b//g")
```

this code works fine with texts without combinations of comma/dot+space, but if it find comma/dot + space, sed doesn't delete word. How can I fix it?

Upd.

Expected behaviour is if input is `word1, word2 word3` srcipt must remove `word1,` from `$content`, but it doesn't. If input is e.g. `word1 word2 word3` it works and removes `word1`.

Comment: @Inian, is it better now?

Comment: `fst_word='word1'; echo 'word1, word2 word3' | sed "s/\b$fst_word\b[,.]\?//g"` works for me...

Comment: in case you are not aware: your code does not only remove the first word.  Try to have `content="abc def abc xyz"`

Comment: @AdrianShum, I know, I wrote it in question: "should remove **all occurences** of the first word"

Comment: oops, I misread it as "remove the first word". My answer is not answering directly :P

Comment: @AdrianShum, I understood your idea and use `sed "s/\b$fst_word\W*\b//g"`,  and it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the position between `,` and space is not considered as word boundary.  So `word1,\b` does not match the first part of `word1, word2 word3`

Your logic can be changed simply to (I am using extended regexp with `-r`, you may or may not need this, or may need some other options for such feature)

```
content=$(echo "$content" | sed -r "s/\w+\W+//" )
```